# Viewing a modified file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I was adding a simple file to one of my programs that updates when I run the program with a particular parameter.

The file updated fine, but it is stored in the /bin directory and I can't figure out how to view the file within the editor.

I can see that the file is updated when I traverse the bin folder manually and open it with notepad.

Is there a way to view the file within the editor?

edit: I have a file in the project already but I doesn't update, instead the copy in the bin folder does; Can I connect the two somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Your `<project>/bin` directory is being filtered from view.  Right click on your project, select Show In->Navigator then you should be able to see your /bin directory and double click your file to have it open in an editor.

Alternatively, you can use `ctrl-shift-r` to open the Open Resource dialog, from the triangle drop down menu check Show Derived Resources, and then type in the name of your file.

The `/bin` directory is managed by the Eclipse builders and so you may lose your file if you do a clean.  I would suggest using a different directory to house your runtime files.